# how to get location-id of instagram api in android

Tags: android, location, instagram

I am making one android application related to instagram so that I read all instagram developer apis after that i tried first user authentication it is working fine I am accessing user data by user-id api.Now i want location information for that i need location-id.I don't know where will i get

```
with user-id:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/**userid**/?access_token=13145898924.f59def8.f14ee72f42f14bea9f56d6dc96924483 

with location-id:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/location-id?access_token=13145898924.f59def8.f14ee72f42f14bea9f56d6dc96924483
```

in first url I got userid and I am retrieving information
in second url i don't know location-id please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: First use facebook graph API to search locations and get **facebook_places_id**. Here is an example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=&type=place&center=37.77493,-122.419415&distance=5000&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&expires_in=5184000
```

Get the **facebook_places_id** and use this instagram location search API to get the corresponding **instagram_location_id**

```
https//:api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?facebook_places_id=273471170716&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

2: Get the **location id** and then make the instagram location media API to get recent media:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/514276/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

3: [Here is an implementation of Instagram location media search using the above method:](http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/places)