# Instagram API get posts by location geotag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is it possible to get Instagram posts by location (geotag) from ***Instagram API***?

I'm trying to look at the following SO question:

[how to get location-id of instagram api in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515771/how-to-get-location-id-of-instagram-api-in-android)

But all the API links not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Instagram disabled the location in their API.

https://www.cbronline.com/news/instagram-api

Comment: Yeah I also think soo, There is another method to achive that?